# How to use struct and union within objectiveC class?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, struct, union

I am trying to access structure within objective C Class.  But I am
not successful.  Can anyone explain how this class has to be tweaked
to make it compile and access the member variables?

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

enum ACCOUNT_TYPE {    
        SAVINGS,   
        LOAN,   
        FIXED_DEPOSIT  
};

struct SavingsData {  
        NSMutableString* accountName;  
        NSMutableString* accountType;  
        NSMutableString* balance;  
        NSMutableString* currency;  
};  

struct LoanData {  
        NSMutableString* accountName;  
        NSMutableString* balance;  
};  

struct FixedDepositData {  
        NSMutableString* accountName;  
        NSMutableString* depositAmount;  
        NSMutableString* roi;  
};

union AccountData {  
        struct SavingsData *savingsData;  
        struct LoanData *loanData;  
        struct FixedDepositData *fixedDepositData;  
};

@interface Account : NSObject {  
        NSMutableString* accountId;  
        enum ACCOUNT_TYPE type;  
        union AccountData *accountData;  
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) NSMutableString* accountId;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) enum ACCOUNT_TYPE type;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) union AccountData *accountData;
```

Answer (score 2):

You should have it static

```
@interface Account : NSObject {  
        union AccountData accountData;  
}

@property (nonatomic, assign) union AccountData accountData;
```

Otherwise you will need to dynamically create it in init (or set it to NULL). Also you need to make sure all these NSMutableString pointers in your struct are properly initialized, to nil or otherwise. Also you should be careful with memory management here as the strings will not be retained when you pass the strings over (you could override the setter/getter for the struct to retain/release the NSMutableString accordingly).

Comment: I was trying to access the variables using (.) operator.  I think I have to use accountData->savingsData->accountName.  That compiled.  Not yet tried at runtime...going to start.  Thanks for your feedback so quickly.  It helps.

Answer (score 2):

Try the following (showing one as an example but apply to all), use typedef and move the name outside the declaration....

```
typedef enum {    
        SAVINGS,   
        LOAN,   
        FIXED_DEPOSIT  
} ACCOUNT_TYPE;
```

The you use...

```
ACCOUNT_TYPE type;  
AccountData accountData;
```

Answer (score 1):

I would recommend to use a `typedef` keyword:

```
typedef NS_ENUM(NSUInteger, ACCOUNT_TYPE) {
    SAVINGS = 0,
    LOAN,
    FIXED_DEPOSIT
};

typedef struct _SavingsData {  
        NSMutableString* accountName;  
        NSMutableString* accountType;  
        NSMutableString* balance;  
        NSMutableString* currency;  
} SavingsData; 

@interface Account : NSObject

@property (nonatomic, strong) NSMutableString* accountId;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) ACCOUNT_TYPE type;  
@property (nonatomic, assign) SavingsData savingData; 

@end
```

Now you can use this class as:

```
Account *acc = [Account new];
acc.type = SAVINGS;
SavingsData savData = {..., ...};
acc.savingsData = savData;
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend subclassing like:

```
@interface Account : NSObject {
    NSMutableString *accountId;
    NSMutableString *accountName;
}
@end

@interface SavingsAccount : Account {
    NSMutableString *accountType;
    NSMutableString *balance;
    NSMutableString *currency;
}
@end

@interface LoanAccount : Account {
    NSMutableString *balance;
}
@end

@interface FixedDepositAccount : Account {
    NSMutableString *depositAmount;
    NSMutableString *roi;
}
@end
```

Properties are snipped, and accountName is moved to base class Account because it's common in all 3 subclasses.